# AWS RDS Error: IAM Database Authentication is not supported for this configuration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to create an AWS Aurora read replica from an RDS MySQL Instance, but I'm getting the following error.

```
IAM Database Authentication is not supported for this configuration. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: cabe107c-d4c9-4d97-9222-b659622a04b6; Proxy: null)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that my problem was that I was trying to create a `db.t2.small` instance, but IAM authentication is not supported for AWS Aurora on `db.t2.small` instances and is not supported for RDS MySQL for `db.t2.small` or `db.m1.small` instances.  I changed the instance type to `db.t2.medium` and that resolved the problem.

[image]

I think (but I'm not sure) that IAM Authentication is required because I had **Enhanced monitoring** enabled, so I **may** have been able to fix the problem by disabling that, but **I have not tested that**.

[image]

Comment: AWS Doc Ref 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Availability and fine-print reads "For Aurora MySQL, all supported DB instance classes support IAM database authentication, except for db.t2.small and db.t3.small."